# How to paginate/split a large string into multiple TextViews/Views

Tags: android, layout, pagination, textview, render

Hi I did a research on google, and tried so many solutions on stackoverflow on how to split a large text into multiple TextViews; but none gave me the desired result, not even near to it.

I tried Ellipsis, Measure and so on to calculate the length of the text that fits to a TextView, but they all failed because they were inaccurate, , , and because I use the methods in a BaseAdapter class, I couldn't use them directly, because the view is not rendered on inflation and the sizes are not available before rendering, so I had to use TextView.post(RUNNABLE), to get the width and height of the TextView after the rendering happens.

As I said, the above methods failed, besides of being in accurate, they messed up things a bit and my app became volatile (Exception HELL).

So I thought if there was a way to, render the layout (inflate) in a dummy View/ViewGroup/Activity (I don't know which one), then access the TextView and measure the size of it, this way, I'll make the code more stable, still the methods may be inaccurate, but it worth not doing further changes.

So I make it clear, I need to inflate my XML Layout in a dummy view, to access a child view's width/height.

**UPDATE**

I can now get the size using following code.

```
public class MyViewGroup extends LinearLayout {

    public MyViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

}

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
MyViewGroup vg = new MyViewGroup(this);
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
vg.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
View child = (View)ViewGroup.inflate(this, R.layout.content_layout_front_fa, vg);

vg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

int measuredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY); 
int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY); 
vg.measure(measuredWidth, measuredHeight); 
vg.layout(0, 0, vg.getMeasuredWidth(), vg.getMeasuredHeight());
vg.requestLayout();

TextView tv = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.content);
Log.e("tvW", "" + tv.getWidth());
```